# Apache 2.2 cut very long URLs from Wildfly

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass, wildfly8

I run a Wildfly 8 server with an Apache server.

We need a lot of options for searching. If you search something you can select many check boxes.

Normally every request will be execute. But if only one option isn't selected, we create a big URL.

We added 2 options in the Apache configuration.

```
LimitRequestLine 100000    
LimitRequestFieldsize 100000
```

Now we run in a limit. If the URL is longer than 8000 characters we get no error from Apache but the URL is truncated. The Apache log file saved only the truncated URL.

If I run the same process directly on Wildfly it works.

Do I need other configurations if I use Wildfly with Apache2 over proxypass?

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `LimitRequestLine` has a bug when used with `mod_proxy`.

Similar issue was reported here [Apache 2.4.16 Response Header value clipped](https://serverfault.com/questions/711750/apache-2-4-16-response-header-value-clipped).

Try using `mod_jk` instead, I have not tried this myself